# Folder contents incomplete

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I'm using this call:

**[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/[ProjectID]/folders/[Project](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%5BProjectID%5D/folders/%5BProject) Files folder ID]/contents**

and/or...

**[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/[ProjectID]/folders/[Project](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%5BProjectID%5D/folders/%5BProject) Files folder ID]/contents?filter[fileType]=rvt&page[limit]=200**

The second one introduces a filter and also an attempt to deal with pagination.  However, each attempt it only returns the subfolders immediately adjacent to the root "Project Files" folder.  No files are returned, and no deeper subfolders, for that matter.

In general, I'm following this tutorial with some updates:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/publish-model/#step-1-find-the-hub-id-for-the-bim-360-account

Scopes for the connection are (for the entire recipe): data:search data:create data:read data:write

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the below request URL **doesn't work with fileType filter**;

[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/[ProjectID]/folders/[ProjectFilesfolderID]/contents?filter[fileType]=rvt&page[limit]=200](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%5BProjectID%5D/folders/%5BProjectFilesfolderID%5D/contents?filter%5BfileType%5D=rvt&page%5Blimit%5D=200)

**Replace** the **contents with search**. Remember to use 3-Legged-Token for this endpoint;

[https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/[ProjectID]/folders/[ProjectFilesfolderID]/search?filter[fileType]=rvt](https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/%5BProjectID%5D/folders/%5BProjectFilesfolderID%5D/search?filter%5BfileType%5D=rvt)